# Copy the result of a query to a table in PostgreSQL inside function

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

If I execute the following command alone in PostgreSQL, it will insert the result of the query in a table called `token_relation`, but if I put this inside a PL/PGSQL function, it will try to put inside a RECORD variable.

```
SELECT * 
INTO token_relation
FROM textblockhastoken  
ORDER BY textblockid, sentence, position 
LIMIT  500;
```

I want to insert in another table like when the command is execute alone. How I do this inside the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you want:

```
INSERT INTO token_relation
  SELECT *
    FROM textblockhastoken  
    ORDER BY textblockid, sentence, position 
    LIMIT  500;
```